# jQuery get top position on the last element in the menu (ignore childrens)

Tags: jquery

I want to get top position on the last element (dynamically) in the menu.

I want to get `menu-item-90` instead of `menu-item-360`

The problem is that i have children in some parent item. what i have try did not work for me.

Here is what i have tried:

```
var nmobile = $('#nav-mobile ul li:last-of-type:not(.menu-item-has-children)').position().top;

<nav id="nav-mobile">
    <div class="menu-container">
        <ul id="menu" class="menu expanded" style="display: block;">
            <li id="menu-item-102" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-4 current_page_item menu-item-102"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-309" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-309"><a href="/services/">Services</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu expanded" style="display: block;">
                    <li id="menu-item-302" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-302"><a href="/accent-modification/">Accent Modification</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-360" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-360"><a href="/voice/">Therapy</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-160" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-160"><a href="/about-me/">About Me</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-405" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-405"><a href="/onlinetraining/">Training</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-210" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-210"><a href="/testimonials/">Testimonials</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-90" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-90"><a href="/contact-me/">Contact Me</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I'm assuming you want `menu-item-90` instead of `menu-item-360`?

Comment: Hi @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc yes exascly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the child-of selector (`>`) to anchor between the `ul` and its immediate children:

```
$('#menu > li:last').position().top
```

JSFiddle illustrating the selection: https://jsfiddle.net/kitsunde/6yyffweb/

Answer (score 0):

One option is first find the last `li` element. Then loop if it has children until you find a child that does not have the class `menu-item-has-children`:

```
var nmobile = $('#nav-mobile ul li:last')
while(nmobile.hasClass('menu-item-has-children')) {
    nmobile = nmobile.last('ul li');
}
alert(nmobile.position().top);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/41nqv73q/)

Comment: Thanks but @Kit Sundea answer was better.

Comment: @user2413244 His won't work if you have the last `li` be a `menu-item-has-children` and you want that last `li` child